# Width transition of text with CSS not working

Tags: html, css, hover, width, css-transitions

I have a div where I want to show the name of a person.

I want to only show the person's first name in the normal state. When you hover, the last name should appear on the right of the first name, with its width expanding from 0 to normal width. All this text is aligned to the right.

If I apply the transition to the last name span it doesn't even show it.
I also tried with max-width (as a guy does here: http://jsfiddle.net/qP5fW/87/ ) but it doesn't work.
So I made a wrapper div, used width instead of max-width and now it works, only it doesn't show the transition at all.

I suspect the problem is with the "auto" property but if anyone knows how to make the transition work, I would be very grateful.

Here's my fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/drywrsy6/

HTML:

```
<div class="name">
  <span class="first">John</span>
  <div class="last-wrapper">
    <span class="last">Doe</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.name {
  border: 1px solid lightgrey;
  margin: 10px auto 0px auto;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 300px;
  font-size: 2em;
  text-align: right;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.first {
  font-style: italic;
}

.last-wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 0;
  transition: all 1s;
}

.last {
  color: red;
}

.name:hover .last-wrapper {
  width: auto;
}
```

Comment: I don't know what "works" and "doesn't work" means. What happens, what do you want to happen?

Comment: You can't transist a width having `auto`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `max-width`, as it won't work with `width: auto`.

Just make sure the `max-width` value is big enough to accommodate the widest text, or you need a script calculating this on load.

As the `max-width` will be somewhat wider than some content, one can have a transition duration with shorter time on reverse, to make it look better on less wide text.

```css
.name {
  border: 1px solid lightgrey;
  margin: 10px auto 0px auto;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 300px;
  font-size: 2em;
  text-align: right;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.first {
  font-style: italic;
}

.last-wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  overflow: hidden;
  max-width: 0;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

.last {
  color: red;
}

.name:hover .last-wrapper {
  max-width: 100px;
  transition: all 0.7s;
}
```

```html
<div class="name">
  <span class="first">John</span>
  <div class="last-wrapper">
    <span class="last">Doe</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Updated based on a comment

Do note, and as [SimoAmi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38706515/width-transition-of-text-with-css-not-working/38707190#comment89210241_38707190) wrote, *"...when shrinking, reversing the animation, if your text is 100px and you specify max-width of 1000px, much of the animation time is spent shrinking the blank 900px difference"*

One way to deal with that is to elaborate with its [`transition's timing function`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition-timing-function), where a custom `cubic-bezier` curve could be one option.

Comment: Well thanks a lot, it worked! I knew I was close, and as I suspected the auto property was the culprit. But it's the first time I've heard that you can't transition to auto...

Comment: @jeanmarc You're welcome, and I made a small update, explaining how to make the transition look better

Comment: There's a problem with this approach: Not knowing the right width and specifying one that's way too big for the text would introduce a delay when shrinking, reversing the animation. if your text is 100px and you specify max-width of 1000px, much of the animation time is spent shrinking the blank 900px difference (the cause of the delay).

Comment: @SimoAmi That is true, but there is no other way when the width is unknown, and using CSS alone (which was asked for). It is all explained in the answer, where I also explicit wrote that to overcome it, a script is needed to calculate the real width.

Comment: @SimoAmi  I updated my answer with a note/link to your comment + added a note how to make that part better. Is there something more that you think I should add to clarify the issue with this approach? ... If not, and the edit is of value, please consider give the answer an upvote.

Comment: @LGSon This solution is also discussed in https://stackoverflow.com/a/8331169/2117996. From the comments, people think of it as a workaround rather than a solution. I gave you an upvote considering there's no cleaner way to do this in CSS.

Comment: @SimoAmi Thanks, and yes, it is a workaround, as the proper way would be that CSS itself calculated a value of `auto` to an animateable number. You will also find posts here were users ask how to animate `display: none`, and the same issue there, not being animateable, and `max-width/height` comes to rescue as a CSS only workaround.

Comment: @SimoAmi Hopefully we will see an upcoming update of CSS, where this is taken care of, either using CSS `calc()` or some other, built-in method.

Comment: Very helpful for me. Thank you.