# CSS3 transition not affecting width

Tags: html, css

So I'm working with a login form trying to get the two `input` fields to expand with a `CSS3` transition. I'm able to get it to expand just fine using a `:focus` selector, but I can't get it to transition. I can get the color to transition, but not the size. This is the code where I'm at right now:
There is no inline `CSS`.

```
                .loginForm input[type=text],
                .loginForm input[type=password] {
                    line-height: 100%;
                    margin: 10px 0;
                    padding: 6px 15px;
                    font-size: 12px;
                    font-weight: bold;
                    border-radius: 26px;
                    transition: background-color 0.3s;
                    transition: width 1s;
                }
                    .loginForm input[type=text]:focus,
                    .loginForm input[type=password]:focus {
                        background-color: #FAEBD7;
                        width: 100%;
                    }
```

I have also tried this:

```
transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
```

and this:

```
transition: width 1s ease-in-out;
```

Comment: You can't transition from `auto` - define an initial `width`

Comment: CSS Transition requires starting point, so you have to add width:0px or 50% or .... somewhere  in 
`.loginForm input[type=text],
 .loginForm input[type=password] {
`

Comment: @MichaelCoker Thank you! I defined it as `width: 65%` and it works! Wish I could give you the answer credit!

Comment: @AdamMcGurk cool, I'll submit an answer. I was looking to see if this was a dupe but couldn't find one. This is close, but it isn't the same https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38706515/width-transition-of-text-with-css-not-working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't `transition` from an `auto` value. If you want to `transition` to a specific `width`, you need to set an initial `width`.

Also your `background-image` `transition` won't work because it's being overwritten by the one that follows it. To use multiple `transition`s on an element, separate them with commas.

```css
* {
  margin:0;padding:0;box-sizing:border-box;
}
.loginForm input[type=text],
.loginForm input[type=password] {
  line-height: 100%;
  margin: 10px 0;
  padding: 6px 15px;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-radius: 26px;
  transition: width 1s, background-color 0.3s;
  width: 65%;
}

.loginForm input[type=text]:focus,
.loginForm input[type=password]:focus {
  background-color: #FAEBD7;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="loginForm">
  <input type="text">
  <input type="password">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks dude! And thanks also for pointing out the double transition which cancels out the color!

Answer (score 1):

> you must define `width` for inputs:

```
.loginForm input[type=text], .loginForm input[type=password] {
   width: 150px;
  //more code;
}
```

> use transition `width` & `background-color` in one line :

```
transition: width 1s, background-color 0.3s;
```

**Full Code :**

```css
.loginForm input[type=text], .loginForm input[type=password] {
  line-height: 100%;
  margin: 10px 0;
  padding: 6px 15px;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-radius: 26px;
  width: 150px;
  transition: width 1s, background-color 0.3s;
}

.loginForm input[type=text]:focus, .loginForm input[type=password]:focus {
  background-color: #FAEBD7;
   width: 90%;
}
```

```html
<form class="loginForm">
  <input type="text" name=""><br>
  <input type="password" name="">
</form>
```